# version-script and hidden visibility

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld

When using `gcc` to build a shared library, it's possible to limit the visibility of the symbols using `-fvisibility=hidden`. I also just learned you can limit visibility using the version-script option to `ld`.

Now I want to know if it's possible to combine these. Say I have a program with the following:

```
void foobar() {}
void say_hello() {}
```

Then I have the version script file with:

```
{
  global:
    foobar;
}
```

And I compile this with:

```
gcc -fvisibility=hidden -Wl,--version-script=<version-script> test.c -shared -o libtest.so
```

When I run `nm` on this afterwards, I find that no symbols are exported. Is there anyway that I can set the default visibility to hidden and use the version-script (or something else) to export symbols?

Comment: In here https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility, it says "Some people may suggest that GNU linker version scripts can do just as well. Perhaps for C programs this is true, but for C++ it cannot be true...", seems not suggested to use this.

Answer (score 13):

Your question makes no sense: why fight `-fvisibility` with a linker script, when you can use the linker script to export *exactly* what you need, and hide everything else:

```
{
  global: foobar;
  local: *;
};
```

Update:

> Because the code I need to use this on uses `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` ...

The linker script works just fine with symbols so marked. Example:

```
// t.c
int __attribute__((visibility("default"))) foo() { return 1; }
int bar() { return 2; }
int __attribute__((visibility("default"))) exported() { return 3; }

// t.lds
{
  global: exported;
  local: *;
};

gcc t.c -Wl,--version-script=t.lds -fPIC -shared -o t.so && nm -D t.so
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000004f2 T exported
```

Comment: Because the code I need to use this on uses __attribute__((visibility("default"))) in the code to mark visibility sometimes, but it sometimes relies on the linker script. The way this is handled right now is just a gigantic hack and I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Your question *still* doesn't make any sense. You may want to try to explain what your *real* question is better.

Comment: Visibility annotations are preferred to linker scripts as they allow more aggressive optimization by compilers. Scripts are still needed for full trimming of external library interface due to issues in [libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2018-04/msg00097.html) and [ld](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2018-04/msg00326.html).

Comment: What if I want to export all functions, but hide everything else (i.e. global variables)?  Or better, just hide the globals and leave everything else unchanged. How to do that via linker script?