# Overriding HIDDEN symbol-visibility with a gnu ld linker script

Tags: gcc, linker, llvm, ld, linker-scripts

**TL;DR**: Can I use a GNU `ld` linker `--version-script` or some other method to promote selected symbols with `hidden` visibility (due to `-fvisibility=hidden` or an explicit `__attribute__`) back to `default` visibility, so they are available in the global symbol table of a shared library?

Is there any way I can tell a gnu ld version-script to promote the `HIDDEN` symbols in the `global:` version-script section to `DEFAULT` visibility?

---

For a rather weird system I need to link a shared library such that all non-static function symbols have default visibility, but all other symbols get "hidden" visibility unless explicitly annotated with appropriate visibility attributes.

If there was a way to tell `gcc` something like the (invalid imaginary syntax) `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-functions=default`, that'd be perfect.

Compiling with gcc's `-fvisibility=hidden` will give all non-annotated symbols hidden visibility.

So I thought I'd promote the functions that have global scope and hidden visibility in the ELF objects to default (global) visibility using a linker version-script.

However it seems like GNU LD doesn't change the visibility attribute when a symbol is named in the linker version-script `global` section. Symbols in the `local` section get hidden, but already-hidden symbols in the `global` section don't get promoted to `default`.

#### SCCCE

Given simplified object (macros expanded, etc):

```
/* Public global variables are annotated */
extern int exportvar __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")));
int exportvar;

/* Internal ones are not annotated */
extern int nonexportvar;
int nonexportvar;

/* Nor are static vars obviously */
static int nonexportvar;

/* For various weird reasons we can't annotate functions with visibility information */
extern void exportfunc(void);

void exportfunc(void) {
};

static void staticfunc(void) {
};
```

with linker script:

Linker script snippet `linker-script`:

```
{ 
  global:
    exportfunc;
    exportvar;
 local: 
   *; 
};
```

built using `Makefile` (de-tabified for easy copy/paste):

```
.RECIPEPREFIX=~

USE_LLVM?=0

VERBOSE_SYMS?=
EXTRA_CFLAGS?=
LINK_FLAGS?=

# Don't optimise so we retain the unused statics etc in this
# demo code.
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-O0

ifneq (,$(LINKER_SCRIPT))
LINK_FLAGS+=--version-script=$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
endif

ifeq (1,$(USE_LLVM))
CC=clang -c $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
LINK_SHARED=ld.lld -shared $(LINK_SHARED)
else
CC=gcc -c $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
COMMA:=,
LINK_SHARED=gcc -shared $(addprefix -Wl$(COMMA),$(LINK_FLAGS))
endif

all: clean demo.so dumpsyms

clean:
~ @rm -f demo.o demo.so

demo.o: demo.c
~ $(CC) -o $@ $<

demo.so: demo.o
~ $(LINK_SHARED) -o $@ $<

# Show object file and full symbol table if VERBOSE_SYMS=1
ifneq (,$(VERBOSE_SYMS))
dumpsyms: demo.o demo.so
~ @echo
~ @echo "demo.o:"
~ @readelf --syms demo.o | egrep '(Symbol table|exportvar|nonexportvar|staticvar|exportfunc|nonexportfunc)'
~ @echo
~ @echo "demo.so:"
~ @readelf --syms demo.so | egrep '(Symbol table|exportvar|nonexportvar|staticvar|exportfunc|staticfunc)'
~ @echo
else
# Only show dynamic symbols by default
dumpsyms: demo.o demo.so
~ @echo
~ @echo "demo.so:"
~ @readelf --dyn-syms demo.so | egrep '(Symbol table|exportvar|nonexportvar|staticvar|exportfunc|nonexportfunc)'
~ @echo
endif
```

#### With default flags (no visibility, no linker script)

```
$ make
gcc -c  -O0  -o demo.o demo.c
gcc -Wall  -O0 -shared -o demo.so demo.o

demo.so:
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 8 entries:
     5: 00000000000010f9     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 exportfunc
     6: 0000000000004028     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 nonexportvar
     7: 0000000000004024     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 exportvar
```

#### With linker script and default visibility

```
make LINKER_SCRIPT=linker-script
gcc -c  -O0 -o demo.o demo.c
gcc -Wall  -O0  -Wl,--version-script=linker-script -shared -o demo.so demo.o

demo.so:
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 7 entries:
     5: 0000000000004024     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 exportvar
     6: 00000000000010f9     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 exportfunc
```

`nonexportvar` has vanished from the dynamic symbol table as expected.

#### With `-fvisibility=hidden` and no linker script

```
$ make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden"
gcc -c -fvisibility=hidden -o demo.o demo.c
gcc -Wall -fvisibility=hidden  -shared -o demo.so demo.o

demo.so:
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 6 entries:
     5: 0000000000004024     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 exportvar
```

`exportfunc` is not visible in the export symbol table. That's expected, since no linker script would override visibility.

#### With `-fvisibility=hidden` and linker script

Can we use the linker script to make the hidden function symbols visible?

```
$ make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden" LINKER_SCRIPT=linker-script
gcc -c -fvisibility=hidden -o demo.o demo.c
gcc -Wall -fvisibility=hidden  -Wl,--version-script=linker-script -shared -o demo.so demo.o

demo.so:
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 6 entries:
     5: 0000000000004024     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 exportvar
```

... it seems not.

Why?

```
$ make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-fvisibility=hidden" LINKER_SCRIPT=linker-script VERBOSE_SYMS=1
gcc -c -fvisibility=hidden -o demo.o demo.c
gcc -Wall -fvisibility=hidden  -Wl,--version-script=linker-script -shared -o demo.so demo.o

demo.o:
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
     5: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 staticvar
    10: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 exportvar
    11: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN     3 nonexportvar
    12: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 exportfunc

demo.so:
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 6 entries:
     5: 0000000000004024     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 exportvar
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 52 entries:
    33: 000000000000402c     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 staticvar
    39: 00000000000010f9     7 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 exportfunc
    42: 0000000000004028     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 nonexportvar
    50: 0000000000004024     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 exportvar
```

It looks like GNU `ld` turned `GLOBAL HIDDEN` symbols in the `.o` into `LOCAL  DEFAULT` symbols in the `.so`.

The linker script appears to have no effect here; the result is the same with or without it.

Is there any way I can tell the linker version-script to promote the `HIDDEN` symbols in the `global` section to `DEFAULT` visibility?

#### Things I can't do

I cannot unfortunately drop the requirement for functions to be visible by default, while all other symbols should be visible only when explicitly annotated as such. I need to match the behaviour of a Windows build that uses a generated `.def` file to export all functions while using `__declspec__("dllexport")` to export only selected other symbols.

Due to codebase size, complexity, shared control, etc I can't go through and annotate every function with a suitable attribute macro.

I can't enumerate all symbols to be exported manually and maintain a handwritten linker script; the codebase has too many different configurations, versions and build options.

I could use a different widely-available compiler and toolchain if that'd help though, and toolchain versions are not a problem. I've tried using LLVM's `clang` and `ld.lld`  with identical results.

Help? Ideas?

Comment: I've also tried using a `__attribute__(section(".globals")))` to move the explicitly-exported vars to a separate ELF section, but that doesn't work because both initialized and uninitialized, const and non-const vars get tagged. So gcc chokes with `var1 causes a section type conflict with var2`. It'd be a pain to collate anyway.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8129782/398670

Comment: This may not be a good idea - by the time you try to change visibility in linker, compiler might have already performed optimizations which rely on hidden symbols (removed unused functions, inlined/cloned them, etc.) and there's no way to undo such optimizations at link time.

Comment: @tmm1 IIRC I didn't and gave up in the end